# compare timestamp value with a timestamp without timezone column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
select * from Test_DB.Test_Tab where column = '2018-05-10 05:00:02'
```

I want to get o/p of this query, the table contains timestamp value with '2018-05-10 05:00:02' for the column, but o/p is giving 0 records.

The datatype of column is "timestamp without time zone", have used as below also but it's not working.

```
select * from Test_DB.Test_Tab where column::timestamp = '2018-05-10 05:00:02'::timestamp
```

::date output is as below

```
2018-05-10 04:03:18
2018-05-10 04:03:21
2018-05-10 04:03:20
2018-05-10 04:03:18
2018-05-10 05:00:02
```

Comment: how did yo check the row exists?..

Comment: yes, the row is present, i want to compare the timestamp column to a value but it's showing any record, if i use ::date then o/p is coming but for whole day records are coming. I want to based on timestamp not date.
I did select * from the table and the record is visible there.

Comment: please show the short sample with `::date`

Comment: 2018-05-10 04:03:18
    2018-05-10 04:03:21
    2018-05-10 05:00:02
    2018-05-10 05:00:02

Comment: You need to provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Its working for me, as your provided all the details. I tested it in PG 9.3. U are missing somewhere for sure.